# Add a compilation option right before the filename of the source with cmake

Tags: cmake, fortran

I have received a code written in Fortran with files named using extension .f95. I know that this extension is not recommended, one should only use .f for fixed form Fortran and .f90 for free form Fortran, but this is the way I received the code.

I have prepared some cmake files in order to compile it. It works well when I use gfortran but it does not when I use Intel Fortran 2021. It seems that Intel Fortran does not accept .f95 extensions by default.

For example, the following does not work:

`ifort mySrc.f95 -c`

But one can force ifort to accept this .f95 extension by typing:

`ifort -free -Tf mySrc.f95 -c`

This is a simplified CMakeLists.txt I have prepared for the project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project (Test VERSION 1.0 
        DESCRIPTION "CMAKE files to compile test"
        LANGUAGES Fortran)

if (CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "Intel")
  if(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS "20")
      message(FATAL_ERROR "Intel Fortran Compiler 20 or newer required")
  endif()
  set (CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} -warn all")
  set (CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O2")
  set (CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "-O2 -g")
  set (CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g")
endif()

file(GLOB FILES_SRC CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "*.f95")

set(LIB_MOD_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mod/)

add_executable(MYCODE ${FILES_SRC})

set_target_properties(MYCODE
        PROPERTIES Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY ${LIB_MOD_DIR})

set_property(TARGET MYCODE PROPERTY LINKER_LANGUAGE Fortran)

install(TARGETS MYCODE
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin 
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib 
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib 
        )   

install(DIRECTORY ${LIB_MOD_DIR} DESTINATION include)
```

I am trying to add these -free and -Tf options to my cmake scripts, but these options must go right before the filename of the file to compile. I have found this [link](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-October/032963.html) where they mention that this can be achieved my modifying file `/Modules/Platform/Linux-Intel-Fortran.cmake`. However, I do not have privileges to modify that file. I have tried adding the following to my CMakeLists.txt right after the `endif()`:

```
SET(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILE_OBJECT "<CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER> -o <OBJECT> <DEFINES> <FLAGS> -c -Tf <SOURCE>")
```

but I keep getting errors. Is it possible to implement this using the CMakeLists.txt file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any downsides to just renaming all the `.f95` files to `.f90` files?

Comment: @veryreverie Thank you. Actually, renaming them to ```.f90``` is just what I did to workaround the issue. But since every time I am getting a new version of the program I'll have to do that, I thought that there might be a way to use ```f95``` files directly. In any case renaming them takes only a second.

Comment: You could likely make the renaming task part of your CMake file to automate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was adding the following option in the CMakeLists.txt file:

`SET(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILE_OBJECT "<CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER> -o <OBJECT> <DEFINES> <FLAGS> -c -Tf <SOURCE>")`

I forgot to add `-free` to indicate that the files are in free form format. By default `-Tf` will treat files as fixed-form Fortran. That was why compilation was failing. So using `CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILE_OBJECT` was the proper way to go to make ifort accept `f95` files.

So now I am able to use cmake with ifort and `f95` files. The CMakeLists.txt section for Intel Fortran is the following:

```
if (CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "Intel")
  if(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS "20")
      message(FATAL_ERROR "Intel Fortran Compiler 20 or newer required")
  endif()
  set (CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} -warn all")
  set (CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O2")
  set (CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "-O2 -g")
  set (CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g")
  set (CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILE_OBJECT     "<CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER> -o <OBJECT> <DEFINES> <FLAGS> -c -free -Tf <SOURCE>")
endif()
```

Thank you both for your suggestions.